# how to use default database for user sign in but after the signed in use another database with rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i m using mysql2 as database and devise for user authentication.

```
before_action :authenticate_partner!
```

I have this line in my application_controller.rb as devise gem suggested.

I have total of 6 tables.

2 of them is in my default database and one of them partner table- created by devise.

What i want is this; when user_signed_in? returns true I want to establish a new connection based on the user name.

I got multiple controllers and I didn't want to create a establish_connection method for each one of them.

So how can I keep my user safe and use different databases?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_partner!
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def find_user_name
     if partner_signed_in?
       ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(                                                                                                                                    
         :adapter => "mysql2",                                                                                                                                                       
         :database => "db_#{current_partner.name} "
       )
    else
      logger.info "log in not succesful"
    end
  end
end
```

This code obviously gives me error when i remove def find_user_name but i can't seem to get in either of the if statements ( checked with logger.info)

So what should I do?

Comment: I think you're trying to build a multi tenant app. This is quite complicated thing to do for a newbie ;)

Comment: well aren we all newbies in something :) i learn when I push myself to the limit.It may be a bad approach but I learn the best in that way.Thanks for the heads up tho

Comment: This looks relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298909/multiple-database-connection-in-rails

Comment: I just wanted to make a friendly joke about your nickname

Comment: @MichalSzyndel i noticed man :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use remove_connection

```
old_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
```

If you have done

```
new_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(...)
```

This can be passed on to remove_connection

```
old_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection(new_connection)
```

for detail [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/11c697383e6fea7834ee1a8ba2815ff0da20f0fe/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb#L87-L89).